# How to fix invalid json issue in pulling data from API using Alamofire in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, alamofire

I need some assistance with my codes. The `json` below was the original response I got from the `postman`.

**OLD Format**

```
{
   "totalCreditedAmount": 2898.3000,
   "periodId": 566,
   "periodDate": "4/26/2019"
}
```

So I created the API service code below. It runs smoothly.

**APIService**

```
 struct DoctorLatestCreditedAmount {
   typealias getLatestCreditedAmountTaskCompletion = (_ latestCreditedAmount: CurrentRemittance?, _ error: NetworkError?) -> Void

  static func getLatestCreditedAmount(doctorNumber: String, completion: @escaping getLatestCreditedAmountTaskCompletion) {

        guard let latestCreditedAmountURL = URL(string: "\(Endpoint.LatestCreditedAmount.latestCreditedAmount)/\(doctorNumber)") else {
            completion(nil, .invalidURL)
            return
        }

        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        sessionManager.session.getAllTasks { (tasks) in
            tasks.forEach({ $0.cancel() })
        }

        Alamofire.request(latestCreditedAmountURL, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            guard HelperMethods.reachability(responseResult: response.result) else {
                completion(nil, .noNetwork)
                return
            }

            guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
                completion(nil, .noStatusCode)
                return
            }

            switch(statusCode) {
            case 200: guard let jsonData = response.data else {
                completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                return
                }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            do {
                let currentCreditedAmount = try decoder.decode(CurrentRemittance.self, from: jsonData)
                completion(currentCreditedAmount, nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, .invalidJSON)
                }

            case 400: completion(nil, .badRequest)
            case 404: completion(nil, .noRecordFound)
            default:
                print("**UNCAPTURED STATUS CODE FROM (getLatestCreditedAmount)\nSTATUS CODE: \(statusCode)")
                completion(nil, .uncapturedStatusCode)
            }

        }

    }
```

But when the `json` side had some changes regarding the response. The `json` format changed and now using the APIService above I encountered error. It says `invalidjson` since the new `json` format is below.

**NEW Format**

```
 {
   "responseMessage": "Request successful",
    "data": {
         "totalCreditedAmount": 2898.3000,
         "periodId": 566,
         "periodDate": "4/26/2019"
   }
}
```

**Edited: getTotalCreditedAmount**

```
var currentRemittance: CurrentRemittance!

func getTotalCreditedAmount(doctorNumber: String) {
   windlessSetup()
   APIService.DoctorLatestCreditedAmount.getLatestCreditedAmount(doctorNumber: doctorNumber) { (remittanceDetails, error) in
       guard let creditedAmountDetails = remittanceDetails, error == nil else {
           if let networkError = error {
               switch networkError {
               case .noRecordFound:
                   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: “No Record Found”, message: “You don’t have current payment remittance”, preferredStyle: .alert)
                   alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “OK”, style: .default))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               case .noNetwork:
                   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: “No Network”, message: “\(networkError.rawValue)“, preferredStyle: .alert)
                   alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “OK”, style: .default))
                   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               default:
                   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: “Error”, message: “There is something went wrong. Please try again”, preferredStyle: .alert)
                   alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “OK”, style: .default))
                   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
           }
           self.creditedView.windless.end()
           self.remittanceView.windless.end()
           return
       }
       self.currentRemittance = creditedAmountDetails
       self.showLatestTotalCreditedAmount()
       self.creditedView.windless.end()
       self.remittanceView.windless.end()
       return
   }
```

}

**Encountered Error**
[image: Breakpoint Image]

My problem is, how can I alter my codes for **APIService** so it will match to the proper NEW `json` format I got. I am having a hard time since I get to used to pulling the same "OLD" format. I am really new to swift and I really need assistance. Hope you can give me some of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, it works to me in array of data:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON {

   response in

   if response.result.isSuccess {

      let dataJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

       if let datas = dataJSON["data"].arrayObject {

         print(datas)

      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Root: Codable {
    let responseMessage: String
    let data: CurrentRemittance
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct CurrentRemittance: Codable {
    let totalCreditedAmount: Double
    let periodId: Int
    let periodDate: String 
}
```

Decode

```
 let res = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData) 
 print(res.data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i encountered error in the part of my `ViewController` where I assigned `CurrentRemittance` for the Model, do I hava to change it also to `Root?` and how  can I call from viewcontroller the values inside `CurrentRemittance`?

Comment: you need `completion(res.data, nil)`

Comment: encountered error `Cannot convert value of type 'CurrentRemittance' to expected argument type 'Root'` in `completion(res.data, nil)`

Comment: do I have to modify this part also?  `typealias getLatestCreditedAmountTaskCompletion = (_ latestCreditedAmount: CurrentRemittance?, _ error: NetworkError?) -> Void`

Comment: i follow all your suggestion I did not change the `typealias` but it still returns 'invalidJSON`

Comment: track your code with breakpoints , also inside catch before completion line do `print(error)` and see what gives ?

Comment: I got the error, the `remittanceDetails` such as `totalCreditedAmount, periodId and periodDate` turns into `nil` in the viewController side

Comment: kindly check above the additional code. Thank you so much

Comment: above content is ok do you have an catch error ? or code pass through try finely

Comment: This is what I encountered **keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: “responseMessage”, intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: “No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \“responseMessage\“, intValue: nil) (\“responseMessage\“).“, underlyingError: nil))** Sorry If this a long thread already.

Comment: I solved the error above. I just fix some codes. Thank you for your answer it solved my main issue. God bless